# How to add or increase speed on every 500m distance of player?

Tags: unity, c#, physics

I'm a a beginner, creating an endless runner game.

I want to increase speed as the player completed the distance and  on every 500 meter speed should be increased.
Anyone have an idea of how to implement this kind of logic?

```
speed=10;
//as soon as player reach 500 m distance
//speed should be incremented
//it should be continuous process on every 500m
```

My code:

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject ground;
    [SerializeField]
    AudioClip clip;
    [SerializeField]
    Transform player;
    [SerializeField]
    public Text LiveScore;
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject gameOver;
    [SerializeField]
    public bool runningScore = true;
    public Text finalScore;
    public Text Highscore, bestScore;
    float distance;
    ball Ball;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {

        Ball = GetComponent<ball>();
        //  PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("HighScore");
        Highscore.text = "Best :" + ((int)PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", 0)).ToString();
        bestScore.text = "Best :" + ((int)PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", 0)).ToString();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        distance = player.position.z + 500;
        if (runningScore)
        {
            LiveScore.text = distance.ToString("0");

            //  Highscore.text = LiveScore.text;
        }
        if (runningScore == false)
        {
            float score = float.Parse(LiveScore.text);
            finalScore.text = "Score:" + LiveScore.text;
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", 0) < score)
            {

                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", score);
                Highscore.text = "Best :" + score.ToString();

                bestScore.text = Highscore.text;
                AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(clip, Camera.main.transform.position);
            }
            else if (score < PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", 0))
            {

                bestScore.text = Highscore.text;
            }


        }

        while (distance > 500)
        {
            Ball.speed += 5;
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`speed = startSpeed + (int)(trackedDistance / 500) * speedIncrement;`

Now your new question is, *"how to track distance of player"*, Since its endless runner game:

`trackedDistance += speed * Time.deltaTime`

`Ball.speed = speed;`

Your welcome.

Comment: "**You're** welcome".

Comment: @nick !! shall i use loop

Comment: @MustafaAhmed no, just put this code into Update() function.

Comment: @nick tracked distance should be length of the track?

Comment: @MustafaAhmed trackedDistance should be 0 at beginning of game, and it will increase automatically towards infinity every Update() call(that Unity calls every frame) by your calculated "speed" value